# Why does cURL download different content than my browser's view source?

Tags: curl, web-scraping

I've downloaded [this page](http://www.quickscrews.com/Part/4080XL) via cURL, and the price on the page ( $118.09 ) does not show up in the source via cURL.  When I view the source on the same page with my browser ( Chrome ), the price is there.  All the other product attributes are there in the cURL source ( part number, description, case qty, etc ).

**Any thoughts on what's happening?**

Here are my cURL settings:

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "",
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 5,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 5,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => "http://www.industrycortex.com/crawler.php"
);
```

**NOTES:**

It's been pointed out that this site does not display a price ( see screenshot below ) until the user visits /home. I've tested this and it is correct.  The website produces a cookie that I was not passing with cURL.  Further, the webserver tracks if the session id of the user has visited /home, and only shows prices if that session id has. The cookie produced by a visit to /home is identical to the cookie produced by any other page.

---

[image]

Comment: Johnny Grabber's answer is likely correct (I regularly use the useragent string to determine how content gets served), however, I just wanted to note that link you provided (http://www.quickscrews.com/Part/4080XL) doesn't list any price. Are you sure you are cURLing the correct page?

Comment: Some sites don't want to be scraped. They use all sorts of devious tactics, including CSRF defense mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The price seems to show after you access `/home` (without logging in) and come back. That's a strange protection mechanism, but it's easily circumvented. All you need is to do exactly that with your cURL session:

1. Set `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` to the same file (I might be wrong about it being required, but it certainly won't harm).
2. Set URL to `http://www.quickscrews.com/home` and do curl_exec()
3. Proceed with scraping.

The price should show now, unless the cookie is set with JS. In that case, you will have to read cookies from your browser and write them to `CURLOPT_COOKIE`.

P.S. I'm guessing the cookie is `sawRegPg=sawit;`. You can try just setting `CURLOPT_COOKIE` to that and see what happens.

Comment: In this particular case, it seems the webserver tracks if my session id has requested /home.  Just having this data in my cookie-jar file does not solve the problem until I have visited /home. /home does not produce a unique or different cookie. Otherwise... this answer is of great help.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to cover this question a bit in section 14 of the [The Art Of Scripting HTTP Requests Using Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) document. Sites can do all sorts of checks and logic that will differ with  "plain" curl usage compared to you using a browser.

Your work is then to record the browser session (with something like [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) and then work on making your curl usage and command line mimic the look of the browser session as closely as possible. That includes user-agent, referrers and probably most of all cookies.

Comment: This article is very helpful with this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites render their pages differently for a browser and a crawler. Did you tried to set another user agent in cURL?

**Edit:**
I can't see the price on the page. It may be that you are logged in and can see the price therefore and cURL (and I) are not logged in.

Comment: I just tried the Windows NT on x86 and Mac OS X on Intel x86 or x86_64 user agent strings from this page and it still didn't render a price in cURL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a site where they were sending content with gzip encoding, which cURL was not automatically decoding. Another thing that can help is to get the user-agent of your browser by visiting http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/ and then using that as part of your command.

curl -A "USER_AGENT" "URL_YOU_NEED_TO_GET" | gzip -d > out.html

I understand that the issue in the particular case was with cookies, and probably not the command line curl, but I hit this issue when I was trying to figure out what I thought was the same thing and adding the gzip -d definitely fixed it for me.